# Entropy-like expression

Tags: probability, variance, information-theory, entropy

I am interested in understanding the following expression:

$$-\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M \log \left(\frac{P(x|y=y_i)}{\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=1}^MP(x|y=y_j)}\right)$$

It seems to be somewhat analogous to entropy as it is minimised when $P(x|y=y_i)$ is constant for all $i$. However, unlike entropy, there does not seem to be any form of symmetry.

My question is if this expression makes sense to be interpreted as something like entropy or variance for a set of conditional probabilities $P(x|y=y_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots , M$? I would also appreciate any references to where I can read more about this expression.

Comment: It might be slightly more recognisable as $-\frac{1}{M}\sum_{i=1}^M \log \left(\frac{P(x\mid y=y_i)}{\frac{1}{M}\sum_{j=1}^MP(x\mid y=y_j)}\right)$

Comment: It can also be written as $\mathbb{E}_{Y} [\ln \frac{p(x)}{p(x \vert Y)}]$ where $Y \sim Unif$ and $p(x)$ is the marginal distribution of $X$ when $Y$ is uniformly distributed. So it is has some similarity to a Kullback-Leibler divergence, only that the expectation is taken over the other variable.

Comment: @Henry Yes, I probably should have written it this way. Or is this a hint? Although I see how this expression makes the link to entropy more clear, it still doesn't look more recognisable to me.

Comment: @a_student Exactly! It seems so close that it must be an established expression...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y \sim Unif \{1,...,M\}$ with probability mass function $p_Y(y) = \frac{1}{M}.$

The conditional distribution is $X\vert Y \sim p_{X\vert Y}(x \vert y)$, such that the joint distribution is $(X,Y) \sim p_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$. From this one can then also obtain the conditional distribution $p_{Y\vert X}(x)$ and the marginal distribution $p_X(x)$.

The above expression can be written as
$$\mathbb{E}_Y \left[\ln \frac{p_X(x)}{p_{X \vert Y}(x \vert Y)}\right]$$

Now, using $p_{X \vert Y}(x \vert y)  = p_{Y\vert X}(y \vert x) \frac{p_X(x)}{p_Y(y)}$, we can rewrite the above as

$$\mathbb{E}_Y \left[\ln \frac{p_X(x)}{p_{X \vert Y}(x \vert Y)}\right] = \mathbb{E}_Y \left[\ln {p_X(x)} - \ln p_{Y\vert X}(Y \vert x) - \ln p_X(x)  + \ln p_Y(Y)\right] = \mathbb{E}_Y \left[ \frac{\ln p_Y(Y)}{\ln p_{Y\vert X}(Y \vert x)}\right].$$

But this is exactly the Kullback-Leibler divergence of the marginal distribution of $Y$ (the uniform distribution) and the distribution when conditioned on $X=x$, that is $D_{KL}\left(p_Y(y) \vert \vert p_{Y\vert X}(Y\vert x)\right).$

And of course, up to a constant, this is the entropy of the conditional distribution.